# How to fit 2 different labels in one tableview on iOS

Tags: ios, label, tableview, cell, subview

I am parsing an xml file , and trying to show in a table view the "titles" and "summaries" of the xml file. I make a subview for every "title" and a subview for every "summary" and try to both fit them on a cell. It works if i only try to put the "title" or the "summary" but not when i try to put both.
This is my code :

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tv cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

UITableViewCell *cell;
UILabel *label=nil , *secondLabel = nil;

cell = [tv dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];
if (cell == nil)
{
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"] autorelease];

    label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    [label setLineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
    [label setMinimumFontSize:FONT_SIZE];
    [label setNumberOfLines:0];
    [label setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:FONT_SIZE]];
    [label setTag:1];


    [[cell contentView] addSubview:label];

    secondLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    [secondLabel setLineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
    [secondLabel setMinimumFontSize:FONT_SIZE];
    [secondLabel setNumberOfLines:0];
    [secondLabel setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:FONT_SIZE]];
    [secondLabel setTag:2]; 

    [[cell contentView] addSubview:secondLabel];    
}



int storyIndex = [indexPath indexAtPosition: [indexPath length]-1];
NSString *text1 = [[stories objectAtIndex: storyIndex] objectForKey: @"title"];  
NSString *text2 = [[stories objectAtIndex: storyIndex] objectForKey: @"summary"];

CGSize constraint = CGSizeMake(CELL_CONTENT_WIDTH - (CELL_CONTENT_MARGIN * 2), 20000.0f);

CGSize size1 = [text1 sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:FONT_SIZE] constrainedToSize:constraint lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
CGSize size2 = [text2 sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:FONT_SIZE] constrainedToSize:constraint lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];    

if (!label)
    label = (UILabel*)[cell viewWithTag:1];
if (!secondLabel)
    secondLabel = (UILabel*)[cell viewWithTag:2];    

[label setText:text1];
[secondLabel setText:text2];

[label setFrame:CGRectMake(CELL_CONTENT_MARGIN, CELL_CONTENT_MARGIN, CELL_CONTENT_WIDTH - (CELL_CONTENT_MARGIN * 2), MAX(size1.height, 44.0f))];
[secondLabel setFrame:CGRectMake(CELL_CONTENT_MARGIN, CELL_CONTENT_MARGIN, CELL_CONTENT_WIDTH - (CELL_CONTENT_MARGIN * 2), MAX(size2.height, 44.0f))]; 

return cell;  }
```

and :

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

int storyIndex = [indexPath indexAtPosition: [indexPath length] - 1];
NSString *text1 = [[stories objectAtIndex: storyIndex] objectForKey: @"title"];
NSString *text2 = [[stories objectAtIndex: storyIndex] objectForKey: @"summary"];    


CGSize constraint = CGSizeMake(CELL_CONTENT_WIDTH - (CELL_CONTENT_MARGIN * 2), 20000.0f);

CGSize size1 = [text1 sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:FONT_SIZE] constrainedToSize:constraint lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
CGSize size2 = [text2 sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:FONT_SIZE] constrainedToSize:constraint lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];    
CGFloat height = MAX(size1.height + size2.height, 44.0f);

return height + (CELL_CONTENT_MARGIN * 2);}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Just to add that when i run this code , it seems that every cell has the correct height to fit both the title and the summary , but only the summary appears on screen and a blank space after every summary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```
cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"] autorelease];
```

use

```
cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"] autorelease];


//Now you can use 2 different texts    
cell.textLabel.text = @"Text1";
cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"Text2";
```

Comment: Ok that works and now i have both the title and the summary on screen BUT as you can see in my code i am trying to print on screen the whole title and summary and not just see the first words and the rest with ...
Now what i get is big cells with text inside like:
"This is the Ti..."
"This is the Summar...."

i dont want the ... i need to print the full text

Comment: For customizing the cell please read http://humblecoder.blogspot.com/2009/05/iphone-tutorial-creating-table-cells-in.html
also dont forget to accept and upvote the question if it helped you :)

Comment: Ok but i think that the way u suggest to do that is different because with this way u can only add a title and a summary. After i do that i want to put the date or an image too , thats why i did it that way and made custom cells to fit my text.
i already read this tutorial : http://www.cimgf.com/2009/09/23/uitableviewcell-dynamic-height/

which shows how to use dynamic heights. do you think u can help me with the approach i am using? I think i am really close to do it cause if i only try to print the title or the summary it works but not for both...

Comment: Please check this http://humblecoder.blogspot.com/2009/05/iphone-tutorial-creating-table-cells-in.html it explains how to add anything to the cell, and adding it in the xib file so it would be easeier for you to add new stuff and to modify size font or locations